# The error keeps decreasing with the increase of number of trees

Tags: r, boosting

I want to find optimized number of trees in Gradient Boosting. However, the error keeps decreasing with the increase of number of trees, I set the number of trees over 1000, but the error still keeps decreasing.

First, I set the number of trees from 100 to 1000, and find the error is minimized at M=1000. Then, I set the number of trees from 1000 to 2000, and the error is minimized at M=2000, and still has the trend to decrease.

What is the common number of trees used in model? Is it usual that the error keeps decreasing?

The parameters and function I used is shown below, as well as plots:

```
for (i in 1:n_Ms) {
    fit[[i]] <- fa.boost.shrink <- gbm(as.formula(formula),
                   data=fa,
                   distribution = "gaussian",
                   shrinkage = alpha,
                   n.trees = Ms[i],
                   bag.fraction = 1,
                   cv.folds = k,
                   interaction.depth = 1)
    cverror[i] <- min(fit[[i]]$cv.error)}
```

[image: M=10-1000]
[image: M=1000-2000]

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that the error keeps decreasing with the increase of number of trees. But it arises the issue of overfitting. Because you have more a more trees, your model is creating a rule for each row in your dataset. Therefore, when you try to predict with new data, it is going to fit bad.

Usually, the way to choose parameters (number of trees in your case) is by splitting your data in train and test and choose the minimun error en your test sample [image]

If you do not want to split it, I will choose a trade off between model complexity and error, like in the "elbow" for kmeans, i will choose around 300, when the marginal trade off between more trees (complexity) and lower error show high diminishing returns.

Comment: the plot i showed was using split train and test set, and then I did out-of-bag average prediction error, vs. number of trees, the shape is same as the plot I showed. I am confused..